# Add space under featured image in singel post

Tags: post-thumbnails

anyone can help me? How to add space of featured image in single post.

[image: How add space under image and above content]

Comment: see my webpage: https://mashamam.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add below css in your css file.

```
li {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```